# Show Progressbar while i get records from a cursor

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apod_eso2);  

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
        "/Database.sqlite"); 
    CursorFactory factory = null;   
    db =SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.toString(),
        factory,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS );

    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurantsApod);  
    KtiriaId=getIntent().getStringExtra(PrevIntent.ID_EXTRA);
    model=DbFileApodEso.getAllEntos(KtiriaId,db);


    startManagingCursor(model);
    //  
    adapter=new RestaurantAdapter(model);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);  
}
```

and the java file i get the cursor is:

```
public class DbFileApodEso {

    private static String TABLE_NAME="TempApodeiEn";
    private static String[] FROM = { "_id","name", "monthPaid",
        "fValue","gotPaid", };

    static Cursor getAllEntos(String id,SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String[] args={id,"0"};
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
        "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,old_id integer " +
        " id1 INTEGER, id2 INTEGER, SNumber DOUBLE, name TEXT, gotPaid INTEGER, 
        monthPaid DATETIME, hmerej DATETIME, user TEXT,tMemo text, 
        GotThere INTEGER)");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TempApodeiEn (old_id,eponimo, 
        monthPaid,iddiamerisma,fValue,gotPaid) " +
        "select _id,name,monthPaid,id2,fValue,
        gotPaid from ApodeiEn WHERE id2=? and gotPaid=?", args);

    return(db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, "id2=?  and gotPaid=?", args, null,
        null, null));
   }
}
```

i noticed that it takes three seconds to execute: model=DbFileApodEso.getAllEntos(KtiriaId,db)
So i'd like to show a progressbar to the user to understand that something is happening, How can i do this?
Thanks for help

I followed the instructions from Shardul and the code is like this:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apod_eso2); 

    //DEFINING A NEW THREAD WHICH WOULD DO SOME WORK AND THEN DISMISS THE DIALOG 
    Thread workThread=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
         //@ albertsmus :call your getAllEntos() here!
         File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Eisprakseis.sqlite"); 
      CursorFactory factory = null; 

      db =SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.toString(), factory,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS );

      ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurantsApod);
      KtiriaId=getIntent().getStringExtra(DiamEso.ID_EXTRA);
      EidosApod=getIntent().getStringExtra(DiamEso.ID_Eidos);
      String comment;   // The generated insult.
      model=DbFileApodEso.getAllEntos(KtiriaId,db);

      startManagingCursor(model);
      //  
      adapter=new RestaurantAdapter(model);
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
      list.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

            someTimeConsumingWork(5000);
            //ONLY ONE THREAD CAN HANDLE UI, INCLUDES DISSMISSAL OF
            //PROGRESS DIALOG. runOnUiThread WILL DO ITS MAGIC HERE!
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ApodEsoListaSec.this, "Work done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
        }

    });
    workThread.start();

    mProgressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Work Notify!", "Working hard, Phew!");
}

 private void someTimeConsumingWork(long milisToWork){
     SystemClock.sleep(milisToWork);
 }
```

but i eventually get the error  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6230): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
why is that? 
And as i try to debug the error i realized that the error comes up when i call: adapter=new RestaurantAdapter(model);
Any suggestion?

Comment: better that first you format your code inside question using "ctrl+k", its not readable, and ellaborate your question that what you want to actually do ??

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)).

1) Show the ProgressDialog in `onPreExecute`

2) Perform the Database load in the `doInBackground`

3) Dismiss the dialog in `onPostExecute`

[Example here](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/116/)

Answer (score 0):

The basic working concept is perform your time 
consuming work on background (non-ui) Thread.

In Android theres only one and only one UI thread.
You must handle all UI changes on that single UI thread
i.e. in your case showing and dismissing ProgressDialog.

```
package .....;
.
.
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
.
.

public class WorkingClass extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
.
.

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //DEFINING A NEW THREAD WHICH WOULD DO SOME WORK AND THEN DISMISS THE DIALOG 
    Thread workThread=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
//@ albertsmus :call your getAllEntos() here!

            someTimeConsumingWork(5000);
            //ONLY ONE THREAD CAN HANDLE UI, INCLUDES DISSMISSAL OF
            //PROGRESS DIALOG. runOnUiThread WILL DO ITS MAGIC HERE!
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ContentProviderSample.this, "Work done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
        }

    });
    workThread.start();

    mProgressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Work Notify!", "Working hard, Phew!");
}

private void someTimeConsumingWork(long milisToWork){
    SystemClock.sleep(milisToWork);
}
```

}

I have defined **someTimeConsumingWork** in this example I coded. Which basically pauses Thread for some long miliseconds. You can replace that call with some real worker thread which is consuming time, in your case **albertsmus call your getAllEntos()** here.

The basic you should remeber is again **you can only call and dismiss UI related functionalities only from UI thread**, there are other classes and methods which can help you out with the same purpose, a UI handler or AsynTask for more complex functionalities.
You can find their implemenation in documentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i put my code exactly where you said but i get an error  Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: I try to get a cursor from java class when i try to load a new intent

Comment: @albertsmus, add Looper.prepare() before entering any loop, to solve this issue. Call Looper.preapare() just after run().

Answer (score 0):

Well i used this code to make it work:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apod_eso2); 
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Eisprakseis.sqlite"); 

    getDatabaseRecs(f);

}
private void getDatabaseRecs(File fFile){   

            new ShowRecs().execute(fFile.toString());

}
public class ShowRecs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { 

    private String Content;  
    private String Error = null;   
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(ApodEsoListaSec.this);  

     protected void onPreExecute() { 

         Dialog.setMessage("Please Wait!..");  
         Dialog.show();  
     }  

     protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {  
         CursorFactory factory = null; 
         File ff = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Eisprakseis.sqlite");
         db =SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ff.toString(), factory,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS );
         KtiriaId=getIntent().getStringExtra(DiamEso.ID_EXTRA);
         model=DbFileApodEso.getAllEntos(KtiriaId,db);

         return null;  
     }
```

//and on onPostExecute i load the records to the intent via Restaurant adapter the three seconds needed to ececute model=DbFileApodEso.getAllEntos(KtiriaId,db); the user see the Dialog

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {  
         Dialog.dismiss();  
         if (Error != null) {  
             Toast.makeText(ApodEsoListaSec.this, Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
         } else {  
             Toast.makeText(ApodEsoListaSec.this, "Ready!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
         }

         ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurantsApod);

            startManagingCursor(model);
            //      
            adapter=new RestaurantAdapter(model);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

}
```